# Unable to strptime formatting for this format 2018-07-26 12:52:18.679605-07:53

Tags: python, date, strptime

I am using Python version 3.5. I am formatting the string `2018-07-26 12:52:18.679605-07:53` using this

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(2018-07-26 12:52:18.679605-07:53, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z")
```

But it keeps on giving this error

> ```
> time data '2018-07-26 12:52:18.679605-07:53' does not match format
>    '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f-%Z'
> ```

Please help.

Comment: what is this part: `679605-07:53` doing inside your date?

Comment: first part is the microsecond and second is tz info. I somehow need to format it via strptime

Comment: That's not a valid timezone string. And it's a pretty odd timezone offset. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime

Comment: this is formed using this - 

      new_timezone = pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')
        current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        current_time = current_time.replace(tzinfo=new_timezone)

Comment: That's not how you create a timezone aware datetime. Please see the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) docs. This is a tricky topic, so you will probably need to read the material that talks about "aware" objects several times. It's important to understand this thoroughly, otherwise you *will* make mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

why the tzinfo's delta can be 07:53?
I think it should be 08:00 or any whole hours.

Maybe you should check the time of the system which generated this time string.
Or just abandon it if you know the timezone.